# Make a group of objects act together without joining in python

Tags: python

I have a multi-stage rocket. Each stage is seperated at a certain time through scripting and hence can not be joined with the others. I want all the parts of the rocket to rotate as a signle object, as shown:
[image]

Doing this programatically, this is what I've came up with:

```
for i in range(250):
    stageOne.rotation_euler[1] = bpy.data.stageOne.rotation_euler[1] - radians(1) #Rotating 1 degree every iteration
    stageTwo.rotation_euler[1] = ....
```

and so on. I've tried having the origins of the object at the same spot, but that does not execute the desired result. Instead, I get something like this: [image]

Comment: One way is to parent the other objects to the one you want to rotate and leave them parented while you are rotating that object.  The code is something like `obj2.parent = obj1`. You can remove the parent when you're done.

Comment: That seems to work; however, when playing the animation, it seems to glitch: https://gyazo.com/637bbcc25dc9e7c0e5ae37352ac65177. Do you have any Idea why that might be?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't understand the glitching; although it does look like a problem with your graphics card might be the source.